# Extra space between inline elements

Tags: html, css

I have this html:

```
<div class="form-group"><!--
    --><div class="input-group" id="fileGroup">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly placeholder="<?php    echo SF ?> *" id="selectedPiture" required data-validation-required-message="<?php echo FOTO ?>">
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
   <span id="filePicture" class="input-group-btn">
       <button id="foto" class="btn btn-default" onclick="$('#fileToUpload').click();" type="button">&#xf1c5</button>
      <script>
        ...
      </script>
</span>
</div>
```

And in result i get extra space below input text. You can see the border in image. I already tried the solutions proposed in similar questions. But nothing works. 
Any tip to fix that?[image]

Comment: Please, provide a jsfiddle with the style you used.

Comment: Providing the relevant CSS in the post would be preferred over _just_ a jsFiddle. My guess is it has to do with some custom CSS that you have applied as your [snippet above with Bootstrap 3.3.5](http://jsfiddle.net/wqfro7vd/) doesn't create the space you've illustrated above.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The problem was in the button css, more precisely padding. I just droped this instruction and increased font size of the awesome font.